# WP7 Get return value from Async HttpWebRequest

Tags: windows-phone-7, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

I have wrote this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = SendRequests.CreateRequest(serverTextBox.Text);
        IAsyncResult result = request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadWebRequestCallback), request);
    }

    private void ReadWebRequestCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);

            using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string results = httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                loginValue = Parser.ParseLoginValue(results);
            }
            myResponse.Close();
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

My problem at this point is that after the Click on the button I need the return value (here loginValue) of the BeginGetResponse to go on with the execution of the application.
I know that this is against the entire sense of asynchronous calls, but, there's a way to wait for the results before going on with the main thread?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you have answered your own question.  On Windows Phone, there is no way to do a synchronous web call.

But you don't really need to.  If there is really nothing for your user to do while waiting for the response from the web, slap up a translucent overlay with a progress bar (or even better, use the global progress bar in the system try) and abide.

By contrast, if you were waiting for a synchronous call from the internet to return (which on a mobile device could take a long time), the UI would be locked and the user would think the application had hung (which, technically, is true).

Asynchronicity is your friend.  Play nice with it.

Comment: You could also overlay the root frame of page with some rectangle that could disable all controls until web call is finished.
And yes. All web calls in Windows Phone are async.

Comment: Its better to set `IsHitTestVisible` of the root frame to false. This will disable all touch events...

Comment: You could set IsHitTestVisible to false, but with no visual indication as to what is going on, the app will appear as though it has frozen (which, again, might as well be true).  You need to give the user some sort of feedback as to what is happening and why they can no longer interact with the application.